# Grok to match new messages line

Tags: logstash-grok

I have this kind of sample data to match in grok constructor

```
Tue
wed
Thurs
```

as of now I use %{WORD:day1} but have some issue because the other word sequence is in the new line
any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What you want is: "(?<day>[\w\n]*)" This will put all lines inside a field named "day", which I find a really rare usecase. Can you confirm that is this is what you want or be more precise on the desired output?

Comment: Hi @SebastiánGreco thanks for your response. Actually im thinking on how to handle multiline text in logstash using grok..lets say for example to handle java exception that being collected from beat to logstash ? is there any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple as this:

**INPUT:**

```
Tue
wed
Thurs
```

**GROK PATTERN:**

```
%{GREEDYDATA:day1}(\n)%{GREEDYDATA:day2}(\n)%{GREEDYDATA:day3}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "day1": [
    [
      "Tue"
    ]
  ],
  "day2": [
    [
      "wed"
    ]
  ],
  "day3": [
    [
      "Thurs"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, yes by using herokuapp, if im using grok-debugger to test it always shows fail